# Change namespace of model for routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model named `WidgetList` that i would like mapped to the `ListsController`. So when i

`<%= render @widget_list %>` it will render `/lists/_list.html.erb` and when I have `<%= form_for @widget_list do |f| %>` it will go to `/lists/{create/update}.html.erb`. Or when in my controller i respond_with `@widget_list` it will know to use the `list/show.html.erb`, how can i tell rails that `WidgetLists` need to use the `ListsController` ?

Is there a way to change this mapping without having to re-name WidgetList ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the :controller option together with :path:

```
resources :widget_lists, :path => "lists", :controller => "lists"
```

Comment: how would you specify this if the model was namespaced? `class MY::Widget`